# Linux VRF and Multicast IP

Tags: routing, multicast

I am attempting to use VRFs in Xubuntu 18.04, but I'm not having much luck when it comes to multicast IP addresses.  I have been using https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/vrf.txt as a guideline.

This is my setup:

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.1/24 dev enp0s8
sudo ip li set dev enp0s8 up
sudo ip link add vrf-blue type vrf table 10
sudo ip link set dev vrf-blue up
sudo ip link set dev enp0s8 master vrf-blue
```

The output from `ip a` is as follows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:0c:19:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master vrf-blue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:5e:ed:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe5e:ed76/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vrf-blue: <NOARP,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:f6:90:1c:c1:1e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The output of `ip route show table 10`:

```
default via 192.168.0.2 dev enp0s8 
broadcast 192.168.0.0 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
local 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.0.255 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1
```

When I ping a local address I can see the ICMP packets on both the interface and the VRF master device by running `tcpdump -I vrf-blue` and `tcpdump -I enp0s8`, however if I ping a multicast address I can only see the packets on the capture running over the VRF *not* the interface.  I have tried setting the multicast flag on the VRF but it has little effect.

```
ping 224.0.0.1 -I vrf-blue
ping 192.168.0.2 -I vrf-blue
```

It is my understanding that the multicast ping should be sent out on any interface attached to the VRF, could anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question over on the Cumulus Networks forum; David Ahern (the author of much of the VRF code in the kernel) replied:

> IPv4 multicast packets can be received on a VRF device -- an unintended side effect leveraged by a user and so not able to make that change. In general multicast and linklocal (IPv6) are meant to be tied to the real device, not the VRF device. Meaning, packet transmit has to be done on the enslaved device. Trying to send packets to an mcast address via the VRF device are *not* replicated per enslaved device.
>
> Or at least that is how I remember it working.

I now have this working on v4.17 with the socket bound to the interface instead of the VRF when multicast IP is being sent.